# Cast variable to User Defined Type in Derby

Tags: java, derby

I am trying to insert a value of a User Defined Type (**UDT**) in **Derby** like this:

```
statement.execute("CREATE TYPE NUMBER_INTERNAL_ID EXTERNAL NAME 'com.test.Id' LANGUAGE JAVA");
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("INSERT INTO test_table (table_id) VALUES (123123)");
```

The table is already created like this (the use of the UDT is not a choice, since it is set up to mirror a real database with this type.

```
CREATE TABLE table test_table (table_id NUMBER_INTERNAL_ID NOT NULL)
```

I get the **following error** when I run the code:

```
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Cannot convert types 'INTEGER' to '"APP"."NUMBER_INTERNAL_ID"'.
```

How can I cast/change the type to make it compatible? The Convert/Cast methods does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you try making an extra constructor `Id(Integer n)`? (Totally unfamiliar with Derby UDT).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use CAST, no.

I'm pretty sure you need to combine your user defined type with a user defined function that can create an instance of that type.

Unfortunately, there aren't a lot of great examples of this. It is hinted at by the CREATE TYPE documentation: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsqljcreatetype.html when it says:

```
You can use factory functions to construct UDTs.
```

You can see a pretty full example of how this all goes together in this article: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/java-user-defined-types-udt-in-java-db.html

It certainly looks like the Derby documentation could be further improved here.